# glusterfs and dovecot problems

Tags: dovecot, glusterfs, shared-storage

Ive got two servers with a shared glusterfs disk, both running dovecot and serving mail from this shared disk. Users read mail only from one of these servers but mail gets delivered to both. Occasionally I get problems when accessing the inbox maildir folder:

> IMAP(user): open(/home/user/Maildir/dovecot-uidlist) failed:
>   Permission denied

The user cant open the inbox. Accessing other folders works fine. If I delete the dovecot index files and restart dovecot everything works fine.

What can I do to make this setup more reliable?

My dovecot settings on both servers:

```
mmap_disable = no
dotlock_use_excl = yes
mail_nfs_storage = yes
mail_nfs_index = no
```

If all else fails I could create a bash script to clean up dovecot index files if there are errors in the logs...

Comment: http://wiki.dovecot.org/MailLocation/SharedDisk currently recommends, under FUSE/GlusterFS, to set both mail_nfs_storage and mail_nfs_index to yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have glusterfs deployed for a few projects, not using it though as the backend storage for IMAP/SMTP storage.

But from experience can say a few things:

First of all I would not recommend anyone use distributed file systems for storage backend on high transactional workloads such as IMAP and SMTP. Since they do not work with them well , mostly because of two reasons: high latency and problems with file locking.

Secondly, have spent quite some time on gluster freenode channel seen people reporting about  Dovecot complaining about constant index corruption gluster does.
So i would strongly recommend you to utilize some other back storage replication solution,
dsync replication or something similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps as it confirms my findings. If there is not a lot of activity everything is ok, but under load things start to break. I will probably have to switch to dsync.

Comment: I'm seeing lots of index corruption which is how I found this question. Will be changing back to old setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put mail_nfs_index = yes, and ensure use a proxy that redirects the same IP to the same backend server always. This link can help:
https://wiki.dovecot.org/MailLocation/SharedDisk